# Postfix relayhost. Connection refused

Tags: postfix, ubuntu-20.04

Postfix is refusing to send email as relayhost. It keeps saying:

> connect to mydomain.com[xxx.xx.xxx.xxx]:25: Connection refused

However the port 25 is open:

```
sudo netstat -ntlp

tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:33060         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      39162/mysqld        
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:21              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      57910/proftpd: (acc 
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      614/systemd-resolve 
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      762/sshd: /usr/sbin 
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:25            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      70265/master        
tcp6       0      0 :::3306                 :::*                    LISTEN      39162/mysqld        
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      61217/apache2       
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      762/sshd: /usr/sbin 
tcp6       0      0 ::1:25                  :::*                    LISTEN      70265/master        
tcp6       0      0 :::443                  :::*                    LISTEN      61217/apache2
```

I have no idea where this problem comes from.
Can someone help me ?

Comment: You are trying to implement relayhost or you are trying to use a relayhost? In latter case your netstat doesn't matter at all, and it seems your relayhost is blocking you. What relayhost operator says, do they have any instructions? Do they require authentication?

Comment: @NikitaKipriyanov What do you mean by "relayhost operator" ? 
My server is managed through a server hosting company and in the dashboard I ensured the port 25 is open in the firewall.

Comment: Are you in charge for the system whose connection was rejected (a relayhost client)? Or are you in charge for the system mydomain.com[xxx.xx.xxx.xxx] who rejected the connection (the relayhost)? Do you understand the difference? The refusal is peformed by the *relayhost* system, not by the client. Client suffers and prints "relayhost refused" because, well, *relayhost* refused and *their admins* must be asked why.

Comment: @NikitaKipriyanov No sorry, I don't really understand the difference. 
Anyway, I've changed some parameters in main.cf: `myhostname = mydomain.com` and `relayhost = [mail.infomaniak.ch]:25`  
and now I have this error: `530 5.7.1 Authentication required (in reply to MAIL FROM command)` Any idea ?

Comment: You seem to be *client*, so your netstat and firewall doesn't matter. // Exactly as it says, you are required to authenticate to your relayhost. See [here](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/postfix-smtp-authentication-for-mail-servers/) for a tutorial and this is the [official manual](http://ftp.uma.es/mirror/postfix/doc/SASL_README.html#client_sasl) where exactly your case is explained — relayhost which requires authentication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your relayhost requres authentication. That is, you need to prove you are allowed to send mail through this relayhost. Usually relayhost operator provides you credentials (some login and password), which you configure in your Postfix to use when it talks to the relayhost.

The configuration of SMTP client authentication (which is used when your Postfix talks to the relayhost which is the SMTP server) is described in [Postfix SASL Howto](http://ftp.uma.es/mirror/postfix/doc/SASL_README.html#client_sasl). Here's how:

In the Postfix `main.cf`:

```
relayhost = [relay.host.name]
smtp_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtp_sasl_password_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/sasl_passwd
```

The first line sets the relay host, the second enables authentication and third line specifies the file where credentials for each relay host are stored — that is `/etc/postfix/sasl_passwd`. In that file you put:

```
[relay.host.name]              username:password
```

Always run `postmap /etc/postfix/sasl_passwd` after making changes to this file, and `postfix reload` after editing `main.cf`. Also restrict access to this file, because it contains sensitive information:

```
chmod 0600 /etc/postfix/sasl_passwd
chown root:root /etc/postfix/sasl_passwd
```

Notice that if your relayhost expects your submissions on another port (for example, when I had to set up a relayhost I did it on `smtp submission` port, `tcp/587`) you need to specify that in both `relayhost = [relay.host.name]:submission` in `main.cf` and the same in the `sasl_passwd` file.

Postfix SMTP client doesn't support "direct SMTPS" (they call it "wrappermode"), where SMTP-over-SSL server is expecting SSL handshake directly on the port `tcp/465` (like the one Google does). It only supports TLS over port 25 or 587 to be started with the STARTTLS command.

Comment: Thanks for your help and your explanations. It works now. I also added `smtp_sasl_security_options = noanonymous` in the main.cf. The correct postmap command to use (in my case) is `sudo postmap /etc/postfix/sasl/sasl_passwd`. In many examples I've seen, the `/sasl/` directory is missing which causes error: `postmap: fatal: open /etc/postfix/sasl_passwd: No such file or directory`. Thanks again.

Comment: Actually you can place this file where you want. Ubuntu made that directory, but it doesn't require you to use it. Just have a consistent configuration, if you use /etc/postfix/sasl_passwd, write that into the config, and if you want it to be in /etc/postfix/sasl/sasl_psswd, modify the config accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

`Connection refused` means nothing is listening on the given port on the given interface. And your netstat output shows that port 25 is only listening on the `127.0.0.1` loopback interface.

If you try to access it from another machine it is not reachable.

To have Postfix listen on all interfaces you need to change [`inet_interfaces`](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#inet_interfaces):

```
inet_interfaces = all
```

If you have multiple interfaces and don't want it to listen to all of them you can also provide a comma separated list of the IP addresses it should listen on.